# Laravel: How to modularize?

Tags: php, yii, laravel-5.1, modularity

I'd like to know something about Laravel 5 which is very important; modularization. In Yii1, all you have to do is run these commands and you are 2/3 done of creating a module:

```
$ mkdir -p protected/modules/myModule
$ echo "<?php class MyModule extends CWebModule {}" > protected/modules/myModule/MyModuleModule.php
```

... or something like that. But, it is as simple as that. Just add an entry into the configuration file, and you are good to go.

But how do I integrate the idea of modules into a Laravel app? I saw a few projects on github that suggest themselves to "implement modularization" into Laravel. It seems that Laravel 5 does not support modules. This is...kinda strange. An appearently "ultimative" PHP framework not being able to do modules does seem off.

So I would like to know:
What steps, and how many, do I have to do to:
- Implement modularization
- Use modularization
- Automatically place routes to the modules

What I thought I'd do was to utilize PSR-4 and namespaces. This was suggested in one of the modules that were found on Github.

Comment: https://github.com/creolab/laravel-modules

Comment: Laravel name modules as "Packages". That's it. Just like Symfony names its modules as "bundles"

Comment: Take a look for laravel modular structure it will help https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/basic-usage/creating-a-module